# Utilise-t-on "en" dans la traduction de "one of them"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> Among the three applications I made, one (of them) was accepted and two (of them) were rejected.

Comment traduit-on cette phrase ?

> Parmi les trois demandes que j'ai faites, une (**en**?) a été acceptée et deux (**en**?) ont été rejetées.

Doit-on utiliser **en** ici ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il ne faut pas ajouter **en** dans cette construction

> *Parmi les trois demandes que j’ai faites, une a été acceptée et deux [ont été]¹ rejetées.*

Pour utiliser **en**, il faudrait par exemple spécifier une destination particulière aux trois demandes :

> *Parmi les trois demandes que j’ai faites **à vos services**, une **en** a été acceptée et deux [**en** ont été]¹ rejetées.*

On spécifie alors que l’acceptation ou le refus de chacune des demandes provient des services identifiés.

<sub>1. Facultatif. On peut laisser tomber pour raccourcir la phrase.</sub>

Comment: Qu'est-ce que le "on" remplace exactement dans ta deuxième phrase ?

Comment: Je suis désolé, j’ai mal tapé. Je voulais dire le “en” (non pas “on”) dans “une en a été acceptée”

Comment: Ça indique que la décision (acceptation ou refus) émane de **vos services**. Le mot *en* n'est pas nécessaire, on se doute bien que la décision provient de ceux à qui les demandes furent soumises, mais ça clarifie toute ambiguïté réelle ou supposée.

Comment: On pourrait ajouter que le `one of them` pourrait être remplacé par "l'une d'entre elles".

Answer (score 0):

Je crois qu'on est pas obligé à utiliser ( en )ici, c'est tout simplement : une a été acceptée et deux ont été rejeté.

Ou

Parmi les trois demandes que j'ai déposé chez vous, une d'en a été acceptée et deux d'en ont été rejetées.

Among the three requestes that I have posted to you, one of them has been accepted et two of them have been rejected.